# Removing beforeunload event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, onbeforeunload

I am trying to remove event using `window.removeEventListener` which I have added using `window.addEventListener` for event `beforeunload` but it is not getting removed. I am trying following code

```
addAlertWithListener(){

   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
     // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
     event.preventDefault();
     // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
     event.returnValue = 'You are currently in edit mode. Are you sure you want to refresh the page?';
  
   },true);
}
```

It is being added but when I am trying to remove the same function using below code :

```
 removeAlertWithListener() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', null,true);
  }
```

It still gives alert message. Am I missing something over here? I tried with and without last param. None of the thing seems working here.

Comment: Why are you passing `null` to `removeEventListener`? It expects the listener function.

Comment: I tried using same function event as addEventListener but it's still not working. @Julia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` are implemented in a weird way in JavaScript, they need exactly the same parameters in order to retrieve the registered listeners. That's different from, like, `setTimeout` where an id is returned.

In Angular, usually I do something like this:

```
private readonly BEFORE_UNLOAD_PARAMS = ['beforeunload', (event) => ..., true];
private isBeforeUnloadActive: boolean = false;

addAlertWithListener() {
   if (this.isBeforeUnloadActive) return;
   window.addEventListener(...this.BEFORE_UNLOAD_PARAMS);
   this.isBeforeUnloadActive = true;
}

removeAlertWithListener() {
   window.removeEventListener(...this.BEFORE_UNLOAD_PARAMS);
   this.isBeforeUnloadActive = false;
}
```

The flag will prevent the listener to be registered twice